# How to patch an object's attributes with `side_effect`

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, patch

So I have a file `some_class.py` with:

```
class SomeReader:
    def read_path(self, url):
        return "read_path"


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.reader = SomeReader(url)
        print(self.reader.read_path(""))
```

And a test file `some_class_test.py`:

```
from some_class import SomeClass, SomeReader

@patch("some_class.SomeReader")
def test_some_class(mock_some_reader):
    def mock_read_path(url):
        return "mock_read_path"

    mock_some_reader.read_path.side_effect = mock_read_path

    SomeClass("")
```

I'm expecting that when I run this test, it will print `mock_read_path` but instead it prints `<MagicMock name='SomeReader().read_path()' id='140701381288480'>`. How do I fix this? I want to mock both the class initialization of `SomeReader`, hence I use `@patch("some_class.SomeReader")`. But I also want to mock the `read_path` function of `SomeReader`, hence I have `mock_some_reader.read_path.side_effect = mock_read_path` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is making a mock of the class itself, not the instances of the classes. The mock replaces call to instantiate `SomeReader(url)` (basically replacing the `__init__` method of the class).

What you want to do is then mock the return value of the fake instance being created by `SomeReader(url)`

```
@patch("some_class.SomeReader")
def test_some_class(mock_some_reader):
    def mock_read_path(url):
        return "mock_read_path"

    mock_some_reader.return_value.read_path.side_effect = mock_read_path

    SomeClass("")
```